How to identify a network?
I am trying to make a local network with two computers (Linux and Windows) via Ethernet, without a router, the connection works fine, but I don't like the name of the network (if it has one) because it appears as an unidentified network. I would like to give it a name.
I saw that the name of a network is given by the SSID, but only for wireless networks and if you have a router or contracted service, which is not my case. So how can I name the network? That is, identify it

What exactly are you trying to use netcat for? You should be able to just create an allow rule for the port your using.

I use netcat to send messages or files, to learn; how is that done? Although if what I'm doing is creating a local network, why does it appear in the firewall as a public network?

Why Netcat has not been updated in nearly 20 years? There are much better solutions.

Is ncat form nmap useful? In the description, it said yes

Well, apart form create an allow rule for the port I'm using also, how to identify my network? Why is not indetify?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-network-settings-of-window-from-public-to-private/

Thank you very much!

“ Why is not indetify?” - What word do you mean by “indetify”?

indentify, sorry.

@Roberto - Are you trying to write “identity”? Because indentify isn’t a word. All major browsers have basic dictionary support

Sorry again,, it's identify. I want to identify my network so I don't have: unidentified network, no Internet connection when I want to connect to it. I don't want to have an internet connection, I just want to identify it to make it private and temporarily disable the private firewall. I don't understand why it's not identified. Is it because I am not connected to the Internet?

Creating firewall rules for ports and applications is a well documented process. What research have you done so far and what have you tried. Please add this information to your question, and not as a comment down here. Please be careful when posting to spell things correctly, slow down, do it right, to avoid confusion and these unhelpful back-and-forth comments that have been happening because of misspellings and other errors.

You can't really identify a network, as such. Networks don't have an identity, and furthermore it would be difficult to define: you've made a network by linking two computers. If you now add a third one (through a switch), is it still the same network? And if you remove the second one?
WiFi networks at least have an SSID, but even then they don't really identify the network: if you add a new access point to your network, you could give it the same SSID or a different one. So the SSID doesn't really identify the network, just a set of access points.
You can identify the other computer by its MAC address.
